# Connection to a SQL Server 2008 instance from Visual Studio 2010 and access all databases

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to access all databases in a SQL Server 2008 instance from Visual Studio 2010. The only tips I have received is on how to connect to a database in a SQL Server. Is it possible to have access to all components in a SQL Server through Visual Studio without having to connect to individual database at one instance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What features did you have in mind? You can query any database from Visual Studio as long as you have the right privileges.

Comment: I guess features was wrong choice of word. Basically I'm trying to get access to all databases, SQL server agent, Security of the SQL Server, etc.. My account has full access to the server.